# CSS text input size

Tags: css

I was in the process of making a login page. but then when im trying out stuff i realize the font on my input is quite small.. What code can i add on to my CSS so i will have a bigger font input size?

**so this is the original one**
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1W44.png)

**So i tried to make it bigger and see if the font inside the input box got big**
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwCua.png)

Comment: use `font-size` to increase font-size, also designing input-elements has some pitfalls as every browser comes with their own version of them, do some research

Comment: Can you add your code on your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type ="text">
```

css

```
input[type="text"]{
   font-size:24px; // change to the size you want
}
```